# More info about spawning functions in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I have often seen people spawning new functions with arity 0 (no arguments) as:

```
 spawn_link(fun function_name/0).
```

where function_name/0 can be for example:

```
function_name() -> 
                   io:format("hello~n", []) 
end.
```

Can I spawn in a similar way a function which takes a parameter? For example:

```
function_name(Arg) ->
                   io:format("hello ~p ~n", [Arg])
end.
```

Should I use

```
spawn_link(Module, Function, Arg)
```

or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use that `spawn_link` with arguments, build a lambda function (`fun`) with the specified arguments or just with fixed ones. So for example you could use, as you say, just:

```
spawn_link(Module, Function, Args).
```

or export your own `spawn_link` (or `start`) in your module:

```
spawn_link(Args) ->
    spawn_link(?MODULE, fun myfun/X, Args).
```

or use a `fun`:

```
spawn_link(Args) ->
    spawn_link(fun () -> apply(fun myfun/X, Args) end).
```

or if you internally call some function with fixed parameters:

```
spawn_link() ->
    spawn_link(fun () -> myfun(1,2,3) end).
```

where `X` in this case is the arity of the `myfun` function in each case.

Comment: the second example is the one I was looking for. Just a question of taste I guess

Comment: The only thing you have to be careful with when spawning a fun is **where** things get evaluated, nothing in the fun is evaluated until it is called which will be in the new process.

Comment: Exactly. This is why you can write: `S = self(), spawn (fun () -> io:format("I am ~p called from ~p~n", [self(),S]) end).`.